# Keep Graphics On Me.Refresh()

Tags: vb.net, gdi+, paint

I'm creating a hangman game in visual basic for a class project, and I've created a function that draws a string when you guess the correct letter at the appropriate location in the word. My problem is that whenever I make a new guess, it removes the old graphics and adds the new one. I need a way for it to save the graphics I drew, does anyone know?

```
Dim newCharArray() As Char = wordArray(rndNumber).ToCharArray
For i As Integer = 0 To (wordArray(rndNumber).Length - 1) Step 1
    If TextBox1.Text = newCharArray(i) Then
        correctLetter = newCharArray(i)
        letterPos = i
        Me.Refresh()
    End If
Next

Dim drawFont As New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 16)
Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
Dim drawString As [String] = CStr(correctLetter)
Dim drawPoint As New PointF(x:=(x1 + 4) + (letterPos * 40), y:=363)
e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `Paint` method is responsible for painting the entire content from scratch each time.

I would maintain a list of all the correct chars and their positions and draw them all each time in the `Paint` method.

Or you could draw each char to a `Bitmap` instead, and then just draw the bitmap in the `Paint` method, something like this:

```
Private canvas As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height)
...

    Dim newCharArray() As Char = wordArray(rndNumber).ToCharArray
    For i As Integer = 0 To (wordArray(rndNumber).Length - 1) Step 1
        If TextBox1.Text = newCharArray(i) Then
            correctLetter = newCharArray(i)
            letterPos = i
            Me.Refresh()
        End If
    Next
...

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Dim drawFont As New Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 16)
    Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim drawString As [String] = CStr(correctLetter)
    Dim drawPoint As New PointF(x:=(x1 + 4) + (letterPos * 40), y:=363)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Me.canvas)
        g.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint)
    End Using

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.canvas, New Point(0, 0))
End Sub
```

Comment: How would you maintain a list of all the correct chars? I cannot hard-code it cause I cannot know which word I'll guessing or how long it is. The bitmap thing didn't work when I copied it over, I don't really know how it works so I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: Put them in an `Array` or `List` that is private to your form. For example: `Private PrevChars as New Collection(Of Char)`

Comment: Steve could you please elaborate? I'm quite new to this and I don't understand how a collection works, especially not how I can use this with the paint event...